# Is there any options like PayPal Adaptive Payments in Google Pay

Tags: paypal, google-pay

I want to add a system into my website where Buyer can pay directly to Seller with or without providing me any commission. Maybe it's can done by PayPal Adaptive Payment System. In Below Image where I demonstrated more clearly about My Issue.

https://demo.erp.place/cashflow.jpg "My Issue"

Actually I want to know, is it possible using Google Pay API?

Advance Thanks to all of you.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this isn't possible. Google Pay facilitates the payment by providing users (the buyer) a convenient way access to their saved forms of payment so that it can be sent to a Payment Service Provider (PSP) to be processed.

That said, depending on region (i.e. India), it may be possible to do this using the [Universal Payment Interface (UPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Payments_Interface). Have a look at the [Google Pay for India APIs](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/intro) to see if that will meet your needs.